# Android 4.0.3 notification action is missing

Tags: android, notifications

I'm creating notification like this:

```
    NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager) App
        .getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        App.getContext());
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setContentTitle(task.getFileNode().getName());
    Intent cancelIntent = CancelDownloadReceiver
        .getCancelDownloadIntent(ticketUUID);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        App.getContext(), 0, cancelIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.addAction(
        R.drawable.ic_stat_cancel,
        App.getContext().getString(
            R.string.notification_download_cancel),
        intent);
    builder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notifyManager.notify(ticketUUID, 1, notification);
```

The issue is that on Motorola XOOM with Android 4.0.3 action is missing. Why? As you can see I'm using classes from support library.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @SimplePlan action button in notification is missing on mentioned device. On emulator with 4.2.2 +  it appeares (didn't check 4.1 version). I know that it's API 16 feature but I'm using support library so it must work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though this is in the support library, it won't work on Android 4.0.x. See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#addAction%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29): "Action buttons won't appear on platforms prior to Android 4.1".

Comment: thx, didn't check it. Is there any workaround to place button inside notification?